# What is URL decoding and URL encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, webapi

I am working on a web API with a team and someone put this code in:

```
params.forEach(function (item, index) {
params[index] = decodeURI(item);
});
```

What is this function achieving?

Comment: `decodeURI` is almost never what you want.  `decodeURIComponent`/`encodeURIComponent` are much more appropriate.

Comment: Google much ? ... literally the first result for the search term `decodeURI`... https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=decodeURI&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: First try to read [about this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)

Comment: This is not about URL, it is about URI. I edited your question and add the JavaScript tag but you rejected.

Comment: I didnt receive any notification of an edit? where would it be so I can approve

Answer (score 0):

It changes the escaped values

`https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript_%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8B`

to the actual characters

`https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript_шеллы`

See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI

That function in particular takes each parameter as escaped (so basically the `name%3Dbob`, changes it to the actual value like `name=bob` and sticks that value back into the params array in the same index, overwriting the old value.

Answer (score 0):

the forEach function loops through the elements in params and replaces each element in params with the decoded version of the URI

Simple example

```
var params = ['%28','%29','%21'];

params.forEach(function (item, index) {
   params[index] = decodeURI(item);
});

console.log(params) // params should now be ['(',')', '!']
```